# Specify a folder to save screenshots to in Desktopmagic

Tags: python

I'm using a module that saves screen shots into my Python34 folder as .png files.
I want the .png files to be relocated into a separate folder within the Python34 folder.

I want this to be done automatically. I was thinking maybe I could loop through the Python34 folder to find all the .png files and then save these files into a new "PNG" folder within the Python34 folder, but I don't know how I would do this. How should I approach this problem?

**Some clarifications:**

The module I am using is called "Desktopmagic", ( https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Desktopmagic/13.3.29 )

I am working with Windwows.

Comment: What module?  Is it configurable?  Have you tried anything yet to solve the problem?  Just asking for code doesn't normally go over terribly well here on StackOverflow.

Comment: [os.rename](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.rename)

Comment: Do you need to just relocate existing files? Then use a file manager for that and this question is off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from the code of `Lib\site-packages\desktopmagic\screengrab_win32.py:getDCAndBitMap` (called from `saveScreenToBmp`), the module uses the provided file name argument as is.

I.e. if you specify it without a path, it saves into the current directory. So, if you wish to save elsewhere, either [change it](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.chdir#os.chdir) or specify a path (relative or absolute) in the argument. Btw, **saving random files under the python installation dir is a very bad idea.**

If you want to prepend a path by default, you'll need to use a wrapper or replace some of the module's machinery.

Comment: Oh I should have been more explicit, I use the saveRectToBmp() function. Not sure how I would specify a path as an argument to that function. Your suggestion to use os.chdir(), however, worked splendid. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: See the source for that function then. I'm pretty sure it does the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can search a directory for a certain set of files using [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html), for example

```
import glob
screenshots = glob.glob('*.png')
```

You can then copy the files by looping over the `screenshots` list and using [`shutil.copyfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile)